# How to maintain ratio in values of JavaFX Spinner

Tags: java, javafx, logic, javafx-11

I have two spinners and a toggle button in my JavaFX application, and I've also set them editable

```
Spinner<Integer> hSelector = new Spinner<>(1,15000,1000,1);
Spinner<Integer> wSelector = new Spinner<>(1,15000,1000,1);
hSelector.setEditable(true);
wSelector.setEditable(true);
ToggleButton lock = new ToggleButton("lock");
```

When this `lock` toggle button is selected I want to maintain the ratio in values of `hSelector` and `wSelector`. So I tried following,

```
lock.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if(newValue){
        hSelector.getValueFactory().valueProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
            wSelector.getEditor().setText(String.valueOf((nv * wSelector.getValue()) / ov));
        });
        wSelector.getValueFactory().valueProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
            hSelector.getEditor().setText(String.valueOf((nv * hSelector.getValue()) / ov));
        });
    }
});
```

But this did not work well. The problem is that when `lock` is selected and I change the value of one spinner and then I just focus(by clicking in text field of spinner) them both one by one, their value changes automatically even when I don't edit the values.

Now, my questions, What is the correct way to maintain the ratio in values of these spinners?, what is the problem in my method? and how to remove the behavior of maintaining ratio after `lock` is un-selected.

Answer (score 3):

Do not add a new listener every time the toggle button changes.  “Add listener” means the method literally adds a listener to the existing set of listeners, so as your code is written, if the user were to select the toggle button ten times, you would have ten listeners on each spinner.

The correct approach is to add *one listener* to each Spinner.  Each listener should do nothing if the toggle button is not selected.  You will want to keep the spinner values’ ratio in a private field, for the listeners to use.

```
private double ratio = 1;

// ...

lock.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        hSelector.commitValue();
        wSelector.commitValue();
        ratio = (double) hSelector.getValue() / wSelector.getValue();
    }
});

hSelector.getValueFactory().valueProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
    if (lock.isSelected()) {
        wSelector.getValueFactory().setValue((int) (nv / ratio));
    }
});
wSelector.getValueFactory().valueProperty().addListener((ob, ov, nv) -> {
    if (lock.isSelected()) {
        hSelector.getValueFactory().setValue((int) (nv * ratio));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to add a listener to the `selectedProperty`. Instead, listen for changes to the `Spinner` **values**. When the value changes, check if the `lock` button has been selected and perform your calculations then:

```
    hSelector.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (lock.isSelected()) {
            wSelector.getValueFactory().setValue(newValue * wSelector.getValue() / oldValue);
        }
    });
    wSelector.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (lock.isSelected()) {
            hSelector.getValueFactory().setValue(newValue * hSelector.getValue() / oldValue);
        }
    });
```

You may need to check the formula you're using to determine the new ratio, however, as it does not seem to work properly; mathematics is not my strong-suit. But this should get your spinners to update properly when changing one's values.